# Advantages of client-side web applications

Tags: web-applications, client-side, server-side

What are the advantages (if any) of a completely ***client-side*** web application, which uses for example Javascript and a backend in form of RESTful web services, over a traditional ***server-side*** application developed with Java Servlets and JSPs, for instance?

*Note: I don't need a long response, just an outline of a couple of ideas...*

Comment: Faster/instant response. That's pretty much it if you want an outline :)

Comment: @OneTrickPony, But, if you have to connect quite often with the backend because you need updated data, it turns into a disadvantage, right?

Comment: There are local databases in which you can keep your data, just like on the server

Comment: Are you referring to an app that runs entirely locally with no backend connectivity at all?  Is your client 'web app' part of another client side UI (ex. mobile app using the browser control for most interactivity)

Comment: @seand I say in the question that the client-side web application would use "*a backend in the form of RESTful services*"... Obviously without a backend it'd be just a HTML static page...

Comment: @MikO it's possible and sometimes useful to have a complete web app on the client with no external backend.  In that case the client often runs a standalone web server.

Answer (score 2):

Clientside is more responsive and looks better, due to absence of full page reloads.